# Rectangular array: Matlab dct2 NOT matching fftw_plan_r2r_2d with FFTW_REDFT10

Tags: matlab, fftw, dct, multidimensional-array

For **RECTANGULAR** arrays, the answers from 2-dimensional DCT using fftw's r2r transformation and MATLAB's dct2 are turning out to be completely different.

Suppose `in` is an `m x n` rectangular array. I compute the 2-dimensional DCT in two ways.

1. Using FFTW's r2r transformation via a C-extension

> fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_r2r_2d(m, n,in,out, FFTW_REDFT10, FTW_REDFT10, FFTW_PATIENT);

```
 fftw_execute(p);
```

2. Using MATLAB: `dct2(in);`

When `m=n` the two results differ by some simple scaling numbers proportional to `sqrt(m*n)`. But when `m` and `n` are unequal, the two results do not seem to be connected anyway.

Is there any simple transformation to convert fftw's out to the output from MATLAB's dct2?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: MATLAB stores matrices in [column major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) order and fftw (using C) expects matrices in row major format. Thus the first two arguments to `fftw_plan_r2r_2d` should be swapped. That is, the code should be:

```
fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_r2r_2d(n, m,in,out, FFTW_REDFT10, FTW_REDFT10, FFTW_PATIENT);
 fftw_execute(p);
```

Comment: I've wasted DAYS because of this. You have no idea how grateful I am. 
Thank you man!